# manageQuery error on Android 2.3: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an error that only happens in certain mobiles. For example it happens in android 2.3 version mobiles (In my case a samsung galaxy mini). In my device it works perfectly (samsung galaxy S2 Android v 4.0.4) 
When I take a photo and try to take it to use in a layout I get an error in the line that I use manageQuery. Here is the code that I am using:

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=(int) 0.9;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    switch(requestCode) { 
    case ChooseImageInputDialog.ACTIVITY_SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Log.d("resultcode pea pick", "result ok");
            Uri selectedImageUri=data.getData();
            actualPath=getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            File file=new File(actualPath);
            bmp=decodeFile(file); //this is new bitmap which you can use for your purpose 

            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 65, os);
            photoByteArray = os.toByteArray();
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }else{
            Log.d("resultcode pea pick", "result not ok");
        }
        break;
    case ChooseImageInputDialog.ACTIVITY_CAMERA_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //bmp = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
            Uri selectedImageUri=data.getData();
            actualPath=getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
            File file=new File(actualPath);
            bmp=decodeFile(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 65, os);
            photoByteArray = os.toByteArray();
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            actualPath = getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());
            Log.d("take pic actual path", actualPath);

        }
        break;
    }
```

And the error is the following:

```
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1111, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.play.playwithme/com.play.playwithme.PhotoEditingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:743)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:256)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1550)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at com.play.playwithme.PhotoEditingActivity.getRealPathFromURI(PhotoEditingActivity.java:133)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at com.play.playwithme.PhotoEditingActivity.onActivityResult(PhotoEditingActivity.java:193)
        01-19 19:16:57.389: E/AndroidRuntime(3024):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
```

Comment: Line 133 of `PhotoEditingActivity` in `getRealPathFromURI()`, there is something null. I guess your URI is null.

Comment: yes is true... the problem is that in my samsung galaxy s2 the value is not null and in the samsung galaxy mini yes. Any idea of the reason?

Comment: Well it sounds like a firmware bug/issue on some devices. I would try to get the hand on the Galaxy Mini and see if you can access the data you need differently.

Comment: I can take the photo first and then take it from the gallery. I know that this works but I really want to put the possibility to take a photo in the app and then put it in a layout. Without this option my app lose a lot of his usability. There is no other way to take it or to make it work?

Comment: As I said, check if the URI is stored in a different way in the intent. You only need the Galaxy Mini or another device where this happens and debug your code there. You could, at least, check if the URI is null and provide the said fallback method. This would at least make your app more bullet proof.

Comment: Ok I will look on it and I will let you know what I get. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this phone (the mini) support external storage? I often find these kind of problems on phones with no external memory.